# macports python_select command not found

Tags: macports

I'm using MacPorts and had installed python_select to switch between 2.6 and 2.7. But for some reason I'm now getting a "command not found" error when running:

```
sudo python_select python26
```

Possibly an issue with $PATH? Not sure where to look for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See answer to subsequent reframing of question:

[macports didn't place python_select in /opt/local/bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152765/macports-didnt-place-python-select-in-opt-local-bin)

Answer (score 63):

`python_select` isn't a command, it is a capability added to `port select`.

To use it:

1. List the available pythons to select from:

   ```
   port select --list python
   ```
2. to choose a specific port (eg python26):

   ```
   port select python python26
   ```

Comment: python_select used to be a command - port select has now replaced it.

Comment: i think you have to `sudo port select ...` and then probably run `sudo python` the first time so it can set itself up (unless your user has write access to `/opt`)

Answer (score 7):

Eh, on my Lion, I use:-

```
$ sudo port select --list python
```

to see available python versions, and:-

```
$ sudo port select python python26
```

No _ necessary for me! YMMV

Comment: How does this improve or differ from the earlier [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6885377/151019)