# macports didn't place python_select in /opt/local/bin

Tags: python, macports

I've uninstalled and reinstalled python_select using MacPorts and yet it won't show up in /opt/local/bin. Consequently, I get a "command not found" error when attempting to run it. Yet MacPorts insists that it is installed. Have even tried uninstall -f and port clean --all python_select.

Is there a more drastic step to remove it from MacPorts and try installing again?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems that [`python_select` has been deprecated](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/29531):

> "python_select" (and other standalone *_select scripts) is gone.
>
> Use "sudo port select python python26" etc.

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo port select --set python python25
```

This will set the Python alias (/opt/local/bin/python) to python25

If you're not sure which versions of Python you have to select from, you can use:

```
$ port select --list python
Available versions for python:
    none
    python24
    python25-apple
    python26
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
```

This shows you that `python27` is selected, and that versions 25 & 26 have Apple specific versions (these are distributed with OS X).

Comment: How do you set the alias back to system python and not one of the versions installed by MacPorts?  THanks!

Comment: First, use "port select --list python" to see what versions of python you have installed. Use the command from this answer replacing "python25" with the version that you want that ends with "-apple" (i.e. you could use "python27-apple" if your an OS X Lion user).