# Why does my system python get run when I've selected a different python using Macports?

Tags: python, macports

I've installed python27 on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.6.8) using Macports.  Here is the output for `sudo port select --list python`:

```
Available versions for python:
    none
    python25-apple
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
```

But when I type the python command, it's running python26:

```
rod:~ $python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 11 2012, 09:09:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I've tried uninstalling my Macports pythons (I used to have the python31 and python25 macports as well) and reinstalling, but to no avail.

I should note that I recently had to do a time machine restore due to a hard drive failure, and I've been finding that some of the soft links seem not to have restored properly.  I wonder if this could be a source of my problems here.  Any tips?

Comment: The result of `which python`: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python

Comment: Hm, that's an odd location for your "system python" to be... Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152765/macports-didnt-place-python-select-in-opt-local-bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your .profile still have the `/opt/local` paths prepended to `$PATH`? If its not present then despite being selected you wont get it by default because it symlinks the version to `/opt/local/bin/python`

Comment: That was it @prodigitalson, thanks! I didn't have /opt/local/bin in my PATH.