# Python versions gone after installing Python 3.3 via Macports

Tags: python, macos, macports

so I installed Python 3.3 via Macports, using `port install python33`

(Using OSX 10.8.2 ML)

Everything worked fine (at least it didn't put out any error message at the end)

So after this I wanted to select this specific python version via port select and first wanted to have a list of all available versions now with:

`port select --list python`

and this now only gives me a list of 3 option:

```
Available versions for python:
    None
    python27 (active)
    python33
```

before I installed python33, i had also the apple versions of python listed:

```
Available versions for python:
    none
    python25-apple
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
    python27-apple
```

The Apple versions are still there (located at: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions) they are just not listed any longer.

Does anyone know how to handle this? (Also, when I use the `python` command in the shell, it still uses the python27-apple version. When I wanted to change the version before, an error occurred. But that would be another question.)

**EDIT (24.10.2012):**

In the meantime I found out about the command:

```
port contents python_select
```

which gives out:

```
Port python_select contains:
    /opt/local/etc/select/python/base
    /opt/local/etc/select/python/none
```

Besides what is listed here, the folder contains these files:

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 admin  272 24 Okt 09:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 admin  170  4 Okt 15:05 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 wheel  363 23 Okt 17:18 base
lrwxr-xr-x  1 admin    8 23 Okt 18:05 current -> python27
-rw-r--r--  1 wheel   26 23 Okt 17:18 none
-rw-r--r--  1 wheel  398 23 Okt 23:27 python27
-rw-r--r--  1 wheel  384 23 Okt 17:21 python33
```

the python27 and 33 file are a simple text file with the following, same content (version No. differs):

```
bin/python2.7
bin/pythonw2.7
bin/python2.7-config
bin/idle2.7
bin/pydoc2.7
bin/smtpd2.7.py
bin/2to3-2.7
share/man/man1/python2.7.1
-
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Headers
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
```

But that's it. I don't know what I can do with this information...

Comment: this may also be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152765/macports-didnt-place-python-select-in-opt-local-bin

Answer (score 1):

> (Also, when I use the python command in the shell, it still uses the python27-apple version. When I wanted to change the version before, an error occurred. But that would be another question.)

This sounds like your search path isn't right. Edit your `~/.bashrc` and near the end put in:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

If you want to have this system-wide, then edit `/etc/bash.rc` and put the `PATH` definition in there. You want to put it somewhere near the end, because the bash resources tend to redefine the `PATH` sometimes (so if you put it at the beginning, then chances are that the remaining configuration will change it).

Anyway, after the next terminal startup the command `python` should be resolved in `/opt/local/bin/`, and the `python` executable there should be a symlink to whichever port version you select.

Update: You can test which Python version your shell would select depending on your `PATH` setting using:

```
which python
```

This should print

```
/opt/local/bin/python
```