# default python on osx lion

Tags: python, macos, macports

Problem is that default command `python` is used by osx python. That means for example if you install py-pil from macports, osx python won't find this module. after `python27` installed with macports, I have command called `python-2.7` available. Earlier there was utility called `python_select` now it's completely gone in a vain, look:

```
Romans-MacBook:~ holms$ ls /opt/local/bin/python*
/opt/local/bin/python2.7    /opt/local/bin/python2.7-config /opt/local/bin/pythonw2.7

Romans-MacBook:~ holms$ sudo port -v install python_select
--->  Cleaning python_select
--->  Removing work directory for python_select
```

I even tried to remove macports completely from system and reinstalled everything, still the same result, python_select is gone in a vain. If anybody could confirm this by trying to download macports and install python27 and use python_select it would be great. because I need to write some compability for osx for some software... and it would be great to know what's the situation with python_select in osx lion.

So there would be two questions:

1. where is python_select in lion
2. how to make default `python` command to use macport python and not osx one.

Comment: MacPorts removed the `python_select` functionality, use `port select` instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152765/macports-didnt-place-python-select-in-opt-local-bin and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116697/macports-python-select-command-not-found

Comment: post this comment as an answer I will accept it =) thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacPorts removed the `python_select` functionality, use `port select` instead.

See:

- [macports didn't place python_select in /opt/local/bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152765/macports-didnt-place-python-select-in-opt-local-bin)
- [macports python_select command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116697/macports-python-select-command-not-found)