# Install pyodbc on Mac OS X via MacPorts

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, macports, pyodbc

My specific question currently: where is [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) being installed by MacPorts? The overall question is: how does one install pyodbc on Mac OSX *with* MacPorts? Full story follows...

I'm using Mac OS X Lion (10.8.5) and Python 2.7 which is running from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`. I had FreeTDS already installed (wrote a bash script using [`fisql`](http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/usefreetds.htm)) but I also followed the instructions at http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2013/01/installing-debugging-odbc-on-mac-os-x/ and verified that UnixODBC is installed. Finally, I've run `sudo port install py27-pyodbc` successfully... and yet when I try `import pyodbc`, I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named pyodbc
```

Sure enough, I do not see it when [listing my available modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/get-a-list-of-installed-python-modules). I am fairly new to OSX, but I checked the symlinks in both `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` and they all point to the same place.

P.S. -- I'm still interested in the resolution of this for posterity, but I simply ran `setup.py build` and `setup.py install` from the `pyodbc` source and *voila*!... works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've learned: MacPorts creates its own Python installation under `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` which is confusingly similar to the system `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. It calls the latter "python27-apple" (assuming version 2.7) and you can see all the Pythons it sees by running `sudo port select --list python` and you can make it use the system Python by running `sudo port select python python27-apple`. Now when you run `sudo port install py27-pyodbc` it should theoretically drop the library into the right folder (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyodbc.so`) ... but it does NOT. You can, however, copy the two files from `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyodbc*` and it'll find them.

```
$ cp /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/* ./
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (v2.7.5:ab05e7dd2788, May 13 2013, 13:18:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
>>> quit()
```

Note that this folder does not require elevated privileges as it is meant for drop-in 3rd party libraries. This is really not the best solution and I'm hoping someone else can tell me off and suggest a better one.

Reference: [How to: Macports select python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201760/how-to-macports-select-python/8241174)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the path to PYTHONPATH so python knows it should look in that directory too.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

After that the import should succeed.