# Select Python Version, Mavericks and Macports

Tags: python

I'm running into something somewhat strange. When I run

```
python --version
```

The python version says Python 2.7.5. I installed Macports. When I ran

```
sudo python select --set python python26
```

And then I checked back with

```
python --version
```

It still said Python 2.7.5. Why is that? Why hasn't the python version switched? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like this has your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201760/how-to-macports-select-python