# how to run correct version of python in osx

Tags: python, macos

So I have 2 versions of python on my mac: 2.7.5 , 2.7.8

When I type `python` in my terminal the `2.7.5` interpreter opens up and when I do `/opt/local/bin/python2.7` in my terminal `2.7.8` interpreter opens up.

How do I make it so that when I type `python` in terminal the `2.7.8` version opens up? Also when I run/compile a python code by typing `python test.py` it should be done using `2.7.8` ?

PS :- I didn't realise until recently that I had `2.7.8` on my macbook. I have installed a lot of modules using easy_install and was wondering if all of these will work with `2.7.8` version too?

**UPDATE:**

i found out that macs use .profile instead of bash_profile. When I open up my .profile file, I see the following :

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-03-04_at_12:15:52: adding an appropriate $
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

**Update 2 : **

I have tried all solutions listed here : [How to: Macports select python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201760/how-to-macports-select-python)

and none work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file `.bash_profile` from your home directory in your favorite editor. If it doesn't exist, create it.

In this file, type this line:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:/opt/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Save this file.

Next, create your own bin directory, with this command:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/bin
```

Next, create a symbolic link in this directory:

```
ln -s /opt/local/bin/python2.7 $HOME/bin/python
```

Close your terminal and open it again.

Comment: ok I did that, it still opens up the `2.7.5` version not the `2.7.8` version

Comment: You need to exit commad+q the Terminal, not just close the window.

Comment: yes mate I did that. It still has the same problem