# How to find the correct version of PyBindGen for Python Bindings

Tags: python-2.7, ns-3

Currently, I am working on the Ns3 simulator and now trying to enable the pyviz visualizer. According to the [doc](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/PyViz), I have downloaded the three dependencies which are

> py27-pygtk
>   py27-pygoocanvas
>   py27-pygraphviz

Now in order to use this, I still need to enable the python bindings which I used `/usr/bin/python2.7 ./waf configure` wanna to check what needs for  enabling python bindings. The result shows that

> Python Bindings : not enabled (PyBindGen version not correct and newer version could not be retrieved)

So I checked the [Doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyBindGen#downloads) and downloaded PyBindGen (version **0.18.0**). The output shows

> Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyBindGen-0.18.0-py2.7.egg 
>   Processing dependencies for PyBindGen==0.18.0
>   Finished processing dependencies for PyBindGen==0.18.0

After I ran the configuration check the results still showed that **PyBindGen version not correct and newer version could not be retrieved**
So I presume that is that because I installed the wrong version of PyBindGen? If so how can I get the suitable version for enabling Python Binding?

I would appreciate if there is someone who can help me figure it out. Many thanks.

S.

Comment: @ Konstantinos I m sorry to bother you again that I feel confused about this and now have no idea to figure it out. I found on [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ns-3-users/qPVUZpfUl9E) that there is a guy has the same problem as I do, just he wanted to install the ns3-dev while I am trying to use pyviz.  Can I use his method?  And also I am running it on Mac instead of a ubuntu, so I probably don't need to download the **python-gnome2** 
What do you say?

Comment: If you download the ns-3-allinone it contains the PyBinGen for that release.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ns-3-users/qPVUZpfUl9E)

Here is the resolution(tested it worked):

follow the [instruction](https://www.nsnam.org/ns-3-dev/download/)
`hg clone http://code.nsnam.org/ns-3-allinone`

`cd ns-3-allinone && ./download.py`

This will solve the Python Binding problem

Answer (score 0):

Updated: after downloading this version of ns3. Solving the python binding problem. Then there will be another problem after running 
`./waf configure`

it will show the result like this:

`PyViz visualizer: not enabled (Missing python modules: gtk, goocanvas, pygraphviz)`

Even though I have installed all of the three dependencies. So after some researches I found that there has [another questions post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ns-3-users/35eruwl_mok/W-GXpEclAgAJ) So there is a guy gave the guessing that

> **"** **Waf found the standard Python here (/usr/bin/python is the Apple path), and you installed the python libraries using MacPorts.**
>   Most probably you'll need to configure Python to point to the MacPort-based Python, or it will not see what you installed.**"**

So according to **[How to: Macports select python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201760/how-to-macports-select-python)**

here is the solution:

`port select --list python`

`sudo port select --set python python27`

Hope it will help anyone come afterwards to use this.

S.