# What is the difference between MacPorts py38-pandas and PyPi pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, macos, apple-m1

I've just switched to MacBook M1 machine and having trouble installing pandas. I noticed that in addition to PyPi pandas there is a MacPorts `py38-pandas` package. I could not install the PyPi pandas due to some compilation error but successfully build and installed MacPorts version. However, after installing the `py38-pandas` I still cannot `import pandas` in Python3 interpreter.

What is the purpose of these MacPorts Python packages and how are they different? Can I make MacPorts `py38-pandas` importable in Python 3 interpreter?

I intentionally do not use homebrew.

I have installed `python38` via MacPorts and made it available in shell. So, `python3` starts Python 3.8 which was installed via MacPorts.

Comment: Which Python 3 interpreter are you using? I'd imagine a MacPorts Pandas also needs a MacPorts Python.

Comment: What's the output of `which python3`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the preinstalled python3, not the MacPorts version.

Perhaps you should read the accepted answer of [How to: Macports select python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201760/how-to-macports-select-python) to understand what happens.

Basically you need to set your `PATH`, that you are using the MacPorts python3 which is usually installed to `/opt/local/bin/python3`.

This is done by the MacPorts in your `$HOME/.profile` by adding a line like:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
```